# Keyboard Shortcut for Hints

Tags: resharper, resharper-6.1

usually when I select a hint such as refactoring a certain line that I am on, when the purple hint icon or the light bulb icon shows to the left, I click on it then select the refactoring I desire.

I don't want to use my mouse.  How do I get that dialog open on the left...really any dialog on the left that resharper unobtrusively shows you?

Just trying to figure out a faster way than with my mouse.  First thing is to figure out how to get that dialog up with the keyboard, not click on it with the mouse.

I'm using ReSharper 6.1, not sure if it matters with keyboard shorctuts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> opens the refactoring options if that's what you are looking for. If light bulb shows up to offer any hints you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to bring up the menu.

Comment: it's alias is `ReSharper_AltEnter` if you need to remap

Answer (score 6):

There's also the Resharper 6.1 default keyboard map for the [Visual Studio scheme](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper60DefaultKeymap_VS_scheme.pdf) and the [IDEA scheme](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper60DefaultKeymap_IDEA_scheme.pdf).

## Update:

And, if anyone is using more recent versions:

#### 7

- [Visual Studio scheme](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper70DefaultKeymap_VS_scheme.pdf)
- [IDEA scheme](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper70DefaultKeymap_IDEA_scheme.pdf)

#### 8

- [Visual Studio scheme](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper80DefaultKeymap_VS_scheme.pdf)
- [IDEA scheme](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper80DefaultKeymap_IDEA_scheme.pdf)

Comment: did the shortcuts change from 6.0 to 6.1? for example the mappings for ctrl+shift+T are different in 6.1, going to type deceleration, and ctrl+shift+N goes to file.  Any chance there is this document for 6.1 mappings?

EDIT: Figured out I was using the IDEA scheme...