# ReSharper, how to show all the hints? any keyboard

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts

VS2010, ReSharper 6.0 Full Edition, how to show all the hints? And is there a keyboard-shortcut?

Comment: You might find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514670/keyboard-shortcut-for-hints

Comment: @Bridge Thank you for your answer, the shortcuts list is very useful. But you might have misunderstood my question. In fact, I want to FIND ALL the hints, which means I don't yet know where the hints are. You know, Warnings and errors are shown on the right column scroll bar with red or yellow colors, but a hint only shows with an underline, which is hard to notice. So I want to know if there's a way to find all the hints at one time so that I can check each one of them.

Comment: Don't you just want the code inspections then? http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__Code_Inspections.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ReSharper Menu -> Inspect -> Code Issues In Solution.

It shows all levels (including Hint) but severity reflected in the icons.